# How can I prevent our IT admins with sysadmin to read data stored inside an encrypted database?

Tags: sql-server-2014, encryption, transparent-data-encryption

I built a web application that stores sensitive data into a SQL Enterprise 2014 database with TDE encryption. My key is safe; I know if someone steals the database file from disk the data is protected. However, if you run SQL Management Studio on the database server, you can query and read the database.

I believe this is because the SQL database loads the database with the masterkey, thus decrypting the DB and making queries readable. But at the same time, I cant prevent an IT admin with sysadmin rights to run queries on the data. If I remove their access to a database table, they could easily re-grant themselves the rights they need to read the data.

Is there anything I can do to prevent this from happening? I thought of saving the text itself in an encrypted format but that will affect my queries to run efficiently.

Comment: Don't give your IT admins sysadmin role on the SQL instance, just your DBAs.

Comment: Are your _IT Admins'_ accounts in the **sysadmin** fixed-server role within SQL Server?

Comment: I cant because they are the ones who need to do maintenance and support on the server, so they will need access to the server.

Comment: @John im not sure, im not really a dba or very skilled with databases but I will read up on fixed-server role and find out. Do you have a link to some documentation that could help me?

Comment: If you know of one of their AD accounts, you can run the following: `exec xp_logininfo 'DOMAIN\username', 'all'`  If the results list `admin` in the _privilege_ column, then they are in this role.  As per @BradC, unless there's a good reason otherwise (e.g. they're also moonlighting as your DBAs) they shouldn't be in that role.

Comment: @JohnEisbrener thank you i will do this, yes I do have all their ad accounts. Forgive my ignorance but do they really need sysadmin to do their maintenance work such as backing up and patching SQL Server? From what I read, sysadmin is kind of like god mode, is that necessary for creating backups and doing maintenance?

Comment: No, patching only requires the ability to stop/start the SQL Services and install software on the server.  Database backups should be handled by the DBA.  I don't have enough context to properly answer you though as there are a (large) number of factors that could influence my suggestion of a "best approach" for you.

Answer (score 1):

Per the other comments, one way to block them is to NOT have the IT Admins in the sysadmin role.  Sysadmin can override anything pretty much.

If they really need a high level of access and you dont want to out right encrypt your data, you could try a combination of a custom server role and/or database roles.  As long as you are on at least SQL server 2012 (for the server roles piece), this would allow you to grant them a more controlled level of access to the sql instance.

The real question is "Do they need SysAdmin?"  If the answer is yes, you'll have to encrypt the data.